# Finding most frequent combinations of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of 1000s of 7-number sequences and I want to know which combination of numbers are most frequent, ranging from 2 to 7 numbers.

So, for instance, in this list:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9
1, 2, 9, 10, 12, 15, 27
```

`[1, 2]` would be the highest scoring sequence in the 2-number category
`[1, 2, 4]` would be that for the 3-number category
etc.

I have a feeling numpy or another framework could help me with this but I don't have any grasp of statistics and I lack the necessary vocabulary to describe and hence find what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why `[1,2,4]` as opposed to e.g. `[4,5,6]`?

Comment: @JohnColeman They do not exist in the last list

Comment: So you want, over every possible sequence of *n* different numbers, which occurs in the most of your 7-number sequences?  And to do that for various values of *n*?

Comment: `[1,2,4]` doesn't appear in the last list either.

Comment: have you tried anything or do you just want the answer?

Comment: You're looking for a counting prefix tree/trie/radix tree - they're not hard to write. If you want every possible substring (and not just the initial substrings as the question suggests), just add all suffix sequences to your counting trie.

Comment: @JohnColeman - that's the problem with inventing use cases on the fly; [1, 2, 4] and [4, 5, 6] should both surface as the most frequent 3-number combinations indeed.

Comment: @depperm I've been dabbling with some code, but I instinctively felt I was reinventing the wheel. And yes, I know I'd be sharpening my skills if I'd delve into this deeper myself, but I really just wanted to know what the solution was called.

Comment: Is this counting done on per row (of `7` elems) basis? That is let's say we have one row of all `1s` and another row of all `2's` and no other rows with `1s` or `2s`, so would we still have `[1,2]` as the winner for group of twos?

Comment: @Divakar No, only in the row itself. Look at it like a list of bingo results.

Comment: @ScottHunter Exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a data mining approach in order to achieve your goal: It is called frequent itemset mining.

Indeed, assuming that :

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9
1, 2, 9, 10, 12, 15, 27
```

is your transactions database, where a transaction is a row (for instance : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), and a transaction contains items which are integers in your case. The goal is then to determine the most frequent itemsets (ie sets of items/integers which occure the most among the transaction database). pymining is a python library for achieving this kind of task (https://github.com/bartdag/pymining)

Comment: I've just tried this and it seems to be working; I took the "Frequent Item Set Mining" example and put in my example data. After sorting the results, [1, 2] is counted 3 times indeed. (I'll wait before accepting your answer, just to see if anything else pops up).